# Extract text available between two keywords and store that text into a list in python

Tags: python, text, data-extraction, information-extraction

In my text file, I have below contents:

fdsjhgjhg

fdshkjhk

Start

Good Morning

Hello World

End

dashjkhjk

dsfjkhk

What should I do I want to extract the text available between word 'start' and 'End' and store in a `list` ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```py
text = '''fdshkjhk
Start
Good Morning
Hello World
End
dashjkhjk
'''
m = re.search(r"Start.*End", text, re.S)
if m is not None:
    print(m[0].split("\n")[1:-1])
```

The subscript `[1:-1]` peels off the `Start` and `End` lines.

You could also modify the `re` to just capture the portion between; assuming `Start` is immediately followed by a newline, and `End` immediately follows a newline:

```py
m = re.search(r"Start\n(.*)\nEnd", text, re.S)
if m is not None:
    print(m[1].split("\n"))
```

Here we use `m[1]` to get the captured text.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this apporach does not work if I have long text file saved as .txt format. When I open .txt file in python and when I run that after writing your code, it did not work. I got the error 'expected string or bytes-like object'

Comment: That's a separate issue.  You'll need to add your code to the question so we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I wrote a code which you have give me. In your answer, you have made a separate variable called 'text' and defined the related strings. I just wrote these strings into a separate .txt file and I opened that .txt file in python with 'with open(path_data1) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()'. Then I wrote your code (from your answer) and I just replaced 'text' with 'lines'. And I got the error like I mentioned in my previous reply

Comment: `f.readlines()` returns a list with each line.  You should use `f.read()` instead which will return the full file as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

See an answer that should resolve your problem. `a_text.txt` file include your text data. I have added two more lines for test purposes.

```
ttp_template = """
Start {{ _start_ }}
{{line1 | _line_ }}
End {{ _end_ }}
"""

from ttp import ttp
import json

def text_parser(data_to_parse): 
    parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
    parser.parse()

    # print result in JSON format
    results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
    #print(results)

    #print(results)

    #converting str to json. 
    result = json.loads(results)

    return(result)

with open("a_text.txt") as f:
    data_to_parse = f.read()

print(text_parser(data_to_parse))
```

Please see the output below:

[image]